# saving API response to coreData, still shows nil when accessing

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

```
  func getGenreKeys(complition: @escaping (_ genre : GenreListModel?) -> ())
    {
        let genreUrl = URL(string: "\(baseUrl)\(genreListUrl)\(apiKey)")!
        
        urlSessionManager(url: genreUrl,toUseDataType: GenreListModel.self) { json in
            
            //json will contain genreList Object , which can be used to get keys
            switch json
            {
            case .success(let genreListData) :
                complition(genreListData)
                CoreData.shared.saveGenreList(json: genreListData)
            case .failure(let error) :
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
    }
```

this above is the api completion code

```
  func saveGenreList(json: GenreListModel){
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        let genreList = GenreList(context: context)
        
        json.genres?.forEach({ Genres in
            genreList.name = Genres.name
            do{
                try context.save()
             
            }
            catch{
                print("error in saving")
            }
        })
    }
```

this is what i did to save data after completion of api fetch.

```
   var coreGenre : GenreList?

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return coreGenre?.name?.count ?? 0
```

this above code is the part of VC that requires to get the coreGenre.name to give the count but it is nill

but when i try to access from viewController by creating a variable of the core data entity class , it returns nill

Comment: Print error in catch block and check error log.  ```print("error in saving", error)```

Comment: `GenreListModel` both as type and instance makes no sense. And in the `forEach` loop you are going to overwrite the data in the (only once) created instance of the entity.

Comment: it prints the data so i hope no issue with saving. genreList.name when printed under save , it prints the name but its not saving to core data base i guss.

Comment: @vadian , can u please brief? the completion part works. the GenreListModel is just a name , for carrying the data after success

Comment: Name variables, functions, enum cases with starting lowercase letter, and name types, structs, classes, enums with starting uppercase letter to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are creating one object, then you update that same object all the time in the loop. Move `let genreList = GenreList(context: context)` inside the loop to create a new instance for each json element.

Comment: @vadian, sure bro, that was my mistake.

Comment: As Joakim and I said, there's another mistake in the `forEach` loop. And – it's not really a mistake – it's bad practice to save the context in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: as @vadian and Joakim said i updated things, but still why am i not getting the data in main VC. is it not updating? or how to confirm if my data is saved or not?

Comment: There is no code about the view controller in the question.

Comment: Have you debugged this or used print statements to see that data is downloaded, decoded correctly, that saveGenreList gets called etc?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, the data is coming until the point of saving ,everything works but apart from saving . i think it is saving but i cant get it to VC. thats the issue

Comment: A table view data source should be an array for example `var coreGenres = [GenreList]()`. And you have to fetch the data or to append the created instances to the data source array. The expression `coreGenre?.name?.count` ist pointless. It counts the number of characters in the name string. To solve your issue you have to provide much more information.

Comment: @vadian , ok bro i will check that !

Comment: You still haven't shown the code where is `var coreGenre : GenreList?` is set. ie where is done `coreGenre = ???`. Currently, you saved it into CoreData, but nowhere you read it from CoreData.

Comment: @Larme , Class GenreList is an entity of core data. I am using its reference to get the number of rows in function tableView

Comment: Your code is still unclear. You have an issue saying it's nil. But what exactly? You declared `var coreGenre : GenreList?`, but are you expecting that's the same as when you did `let genreList = GenreList(context: context)`? You talk about CoreData, you have a save, but no read. It's like putting an object into a drawer, but not opening back the drawer to retrieve the object, and you ask why don't I have the object. See? Where is you retrieve action? Or is your issue only because of `getGenreKeys()`? Where is it called? How?

Comment: @Larme ! ,  I was trying to put the only the required to succinct  the code. What I am hoping achieve with the first code is to get the json after completion. And that’s working. Secondly , in the saveGenreList function , I am using a forEach loop to save each element to the GenreList entity in core data. Third, since I am hoping the data is saved, I am trying to access the GenreList entity in VC by assigning a variable ‘ coreGenre’.

Comment: Your question is why `var coreGenre : GenreList?` is nil, right? So let's start on how that value is inialized? That code is missing. Now, if it initialized from a CoreData record, okay, you can show how you save it, but it's still missing how it's initialized. So what's that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong?

I'll base my answer on code [there](https://github.com/mrSolutionist/netflixClone/tree/test). In your GitHub account where you shared that code.

First issue:

You have:

```
var genrelist : GenreListModel? {
    didSet{
        //after getting data a table needs to reload and ui elements needs to be used in main thread only
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
        }
    }
}

var coreGenre : [GenreList]?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ...
    ApiManager.shared.getGenreKeys { genre in
        self.genrelist = genre
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return coreGenre?.count ?? 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
    genrelist?.genres?[indexPath.row].id
    ...
    cell.genreLabel.text = genrelist?.genres?[indexPath.row].name
    ...
}
```

First issue:
`coreGenre` IS NEVER SET! `genreList` is set, but not `coreGenre`. So don't expect it to be something else that `nil`!
You didn't write `coreGenre = something`
So `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)` will always return `0`.

Make your choice. Either `genreList` or `coreGenre`:

```
ApiManager.shared.getGenreKeys { genreList in
        self.coreGenre = genreList.genres
}
```

&

```
var coreGenre: [GenreList] {
    didSet { DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() } }
}
```

And remove `var genreList`

Or, remove `coreGenre`.

That should fix the `UITableView`, and that's where your question is misleading: There is no CoreData here. In the `completion` of `getGenreKeys()`, you return the value. CoreData saves the value in the method, but that's all.

It's:

```
API -> Parse Value -> Save in CoreData
                   -> Completion        -> Reload TableView to Display
```

Now in your CoreData stack, you have a method `saveGenreList(json:)`. Assuming it works, you save it but never retrieve it.

There is no `NSFetchRequest` in your code. Look how to execute fetch in CoreData.

Just stop thinking about `CoreData`, to understand the issue:

```
let retrieveValueFromAPI = "I got it"
let savedValue = retrieveValueFromAPI // (1)
return retrieveValueFromAPI
```

In (1), you'll have an unused variable warning from Xcode. It's exactly the same issue. Here its a "RAM value" instead of a disk value, but that's the same logic. You don't use what you've saved.

You need to continue working and debug. And debug is not only fixing the issue. There are a few steps:

- Reproduce the issue
- Find its origin/understand what could be the issue
- Fix the issue

Finding its origin, and why, are the steps you were missing, either by misconcept, or not enough step by step research in your code.